# Slow evaluation in M13.1 when using auto-completion on package symbols

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, front-end

**Bug introduced in version 13.1.0**

---

I see an extreme slowdown when evaluating cells in Mathematica 13.1.0 if auto-completion of package symbols was previously triggered. I am using macOS 10.14.

##### Questions

- Does this happen with newer versions of macOS?
- Does this happen on Windows and Linux?
- Why does it happen only with some, but not all packages?

##### Steps to reproduce the problem

- Install and load a package. I could reproduce this with my [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/), with [GitLink](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink), as well as with some private packages I use. I was *not* able to reproduce it with any of the standard add-ons that are bundled with Mathematica, or with MaTeX. If you experiment with GitLink, note that the version I linked to does not support Apple Silicon.
- Evaluate an expression that contains symbols from the package you just loaded. Type in the package symbol manually, and make sure that you trigger auto-completion while doing so. This is a necessary prerequisite to triggering the problem. If the auto-completion box does not pop up automatically, you use Command-K (macOS) or Ctrl-K (Windows or Linux).
- The evaluation will be very slow, but only when auto-completion was triggered prior to it.

Here is a screen recording showing that the problem occurs after typing the code manually using auto-completion, but does not occur when re-evaluating the same cell without re-typing it.

[image]

##### Notes

- This is a new problem in M13.1.0, and does not affect M13.0.1 or earlier.
- Turning off auto-completion in the Option Inspector makes the problem go away, but using Mathematica without auto-completion is a pain. If *automatic* auto-completion is disables, but it is triggered manually with Command-K, the problem returns. The relevant option is called `ShowCodeAssist` and should be toggled within the Global Preferences section of the Option Inspector.

Comment: Note: This was already reported to Wolfram, but input from others would help to have a clearer picture of what's going on.

Comment: I don't see any delays when using IGraph/M 0.5.1 (October 12, 2020) with MM13.1 on Windows. I will upgrade IGraph to see if that changes anything.

Comment: version IGraph/M 0.6.1 (July 16, 2022) seems a bit faster. No problems. I hope this helps..

Comment: This is actually super annoying for me as well. I have a delay of about 2s every time...any update?

Comment: @Pueggel Please see the answer.

Answer (score 6):

WRI suggested the following workaround until this gets fixed. Open the following file:

```
NotebookOpen@FileNameJoin[{
   $InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", 
   "AutocompletionData", "Main", "documentedContexts.m"}]
```

Add the context of the affected package to the end of the list, i.e. for IGraph/M, add `` "IGraphM`" `` to the end of the list.

The slowdown is a bug in Mathematica 13.1.0. The problem is related to trying to look up the documentation page of symbols that don't have their separate documentation. IGraph/M will get per-symbol documentation at some point but we are not there yet, as this would take considerable work.